# Does vector<T>::push_back() call any matching constructor of its type T?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I used a `reference_wrapper` recently like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

struct A {
};

struct B {
    B() {};
    B(A& aA) {};
    B(const B&) = default;
};

int main () {
    A a;
    B b;

    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<B>> rvector;
    rvector.push_back(std::reference_wrapper<B>(b)); // (1)
    rvector.push_back(b); // (2)
```

1 and 2, are both compiling and working just fine and I wonder which is the right one! So I thought that the following could work too:

```
    std::vector<B> bvector;
    bvector.push_back(a); // (3)
    bvector.push_back(b); // (4)
    std::cout << bvector.size() << "\n";
```

yeap, it works! So I came to the conclusion that `push_back` just calls the type's `T` constructor with the given parameter. [Documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) though mentions that the parameter is of type `T` and eventually the copy/move ctor.

When I tried 1 and 2 with `shared_ptr` though:

```
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<B>> pvector;
    pvector.push_back(std::shared_ptr<B>(new B())); // (5)
    pvector.push_back(new B()); // (6)
```

I get

```
no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::shared_ptr<B> >::push_back(B*)'
```

- Why 2 and even 3 work but 6 doesn't?
- There should be a `shared_ptr<B>`constructor that takes `B*` as parameter, isn't there? So, why 6 does not compile (since 3 does)?
- Since 3 compiles and works just fine, would it be ok to use and count on it (if it wasn't a bad approach since there is the `emplace_back`)?

Comment: Please limit posts to just one question.

Comment: I guess you just counted the bullets!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why 2 and even 3 work but 6 doesn't?

[`std::vector::push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) takes `T` as parameter, then it'll work if you're passing something which could be converted to `T` implicitly.

(2) works because `B` could convert to `std::reference_wrapper<B>` implicitly. (3) works because `A` could convert to `B` implicitly. (6) doesn't work because `B*` can't convert to `shared_ptr<B>` implicitly. Note that [the constructor of `shared_ptr` taking raw pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) is marked as `explicit`.

> Since 3 compiles and works just fine, would it be ok to use and count on it (if it wasn't a bad approach since there is the emplace_back)?

Yes you can use it, but note that [`emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) is more efficient sometimes; it will construct the element in-place directly without any implicit conversion, instead of constructing a temporary `T` and then move it into the `vector` (as `push_back`).

Answer (score 1):

[Constructor of `std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/reference_wrapper) is a [converting constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor) that allows implicit conversion from `B` to `std::reference_wrapper<B>` and that's why (2) works.

However [constructor (3) of `std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) is [`explicit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit), hence you have to specify `std::shared_ptr<B>` explicitly in (5).

Answer (score 1):

`push_back` takes a `T const&` or a `T&&`.

So if we have a `vector<X>`, `push_back(expr)` works if `X const& x=expr;` compiles or `X&& x=expr;` compiles, and it isn't ambiguous which matches better, and the move/copy from the argument is allowed.

Those compile for your first cases, but not your shared ptr from ptr, because `X x=expr;` doesn't call `explicit` constructors.

You can `vec.emplace_back(expr)` if you want to consider explicit constructors.